# In JavaScript, how does join vs += on a string handle utf encodings differently?

Tags: javascript, ascii, utf-16, fromcharcode

What is the difference between the below two operations that accounts for the one with `join` resulting in `"÷C "` where the other with reduce results in `"÷C"`?

## 1

```
// returns "÷C "
["f7","43"].map(x=>'0x'+ x).map(String.fromCharCode).join('');
```

## 2

```
// returns "÷C"
["f7","43"].map(x=>'0x'+x).reduce((a, c) => { 
    a += String.fromCharCode(c); 
    return a 
}, '');
```

Comment: if you want to read a string as hexadecimal, use `parseInt(string, 16)`, not adding `0x` prefix.

Comment: data printed is wrong... ist sample produce `"÷" ` not `"÷C"`. Wrong info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.fromCharCode` accepts multiple arguments. Each argument will be interpreted as a code unit. In the first code, since `.map` also provides arguments for the index and the array being iterated over:

```
["f7","43"].map(x=>'0x'+ x).map(String.fromCharCode).join('');
```

is equivalent to

```
["f7","43"]
  .map(x=>'0x'+ x)
  .map((str, i, arr) => (
    String.fromCharCode(str, i, arr)
  )
  .join('');
```

Which has unexpected results.

Explicitly pass *only* the `str` instead, and it'll result in the same as in the second snippet:

```js
const result = ["f7","43"]
  .map(x=>'0x'+ x)
  .map((str) => (
    String.fromCharCode(str)
  ))
  .join('');
console.log(result);
```

(still, calling `fromCharCode` with something that isn't a number is weird and confusing, better to do it explicitly as Barmar mentions)

Comment: he's depending on `fromCharCode()` converting the string to int, and doing it in hex because of 0x prefix